# Problem: Having file name contain Space and fetch the file

Tags: linux, shell-script, hp-ux

I am trying to get all file which is reside in one folder and file name have space like

```
1)File Test 050791.xml
```

and i am fetching using below command

```
export srcfileTimeCheck="$(find $dir -type f -mtime +1)"
```

but this command give me error like

```
find: can not stat File
find: can not stat Test
find: can not stat 050791.xml
```

Please help me how can i find all file which having space also.
Note: I Have tried

```
1) xrags -0 -I '{}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable name is a misnomer :)

To make the issue go away wrap the variable in double-quotes.

```
export srcfileTimeCheck="$(find "$dir" -type f -mtime +1)"
```